# Finding the IP Address of a Raspberry Pi without access to the router admin page

Tags: pi-3

Can you find out the IP Address of a Pi on a network where you don't have admin access (e.g. public Wi-Fi)?
Can you do this via the Pi itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Pi itself you can find the IP address with the [`ip addr`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ip) or [`hostname -I`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname) commands or from the Network Manager GUI (probably).

The [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ip-address.md) has some tips on how to find the IP address from elsewhere on the network but something like `ping raspberrypi.local` might be the easier one to try first, depending on the OS you're using on the other device and if you've changed your Pi settings.

Comment: Thanks for these suggesttions. I will try them out.

Comment: And by the way, check out my other question on Google Drive (you can do this via my profile)

Answer (score 4):

If the local network is small (e.g. local IPv4 segment) or you know the exact pool of IP addresses of interest, you can find an open SSH port in seconds using `nmap`:

```
nmap -sS -p 22 192.168.10.0/24
```

Comment: What happens if the network is huge? Any other way?

Comment: @You can still use the same command, but depending on how huge the network is, it will take more time. It's still faster than reading router admin pages though.

Comment: I would use - preferably as root: `nmap -n -sP 192.168.10.0/24` (ping sweep, no name resolution) because the SSH service may not be active on the Raspberry PI. In fact SSH is disabled on a default install. On the other hand the Raspberry PI will normally always respond to a ping. If you have lots of machines on the network you can also filter out by looking at the first half of the MAC addresses (DC:A6:32 or B8:27:EB). This nmap scan has to be done from another machine on the same network.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Terminal and type

**ifconfig**

Output:
It will list the Ip address of LAN,Wifi etc.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated. You should better advice to use `ip addr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got access to your Pi, you can use [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105962/83790). If not, use the command line of your laptop/linux pc/mac. Some of this won't work in Windows unless you've installed [cygwin](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41382/how-to-use-linux-commands-in-windows-with-cygwin/) or the [bash shell for windows](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10)

Try this first:

```
$ arp -a | grep --ignore-case b8:27:eb
```

If you get a reply that looks like this, then there's your IP address!

> ? (192.168.1.131) at b8:27:eb:cd:2f:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]

If not, then your pi's arp cache doesn't have the IP address ([details if you're interested](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/ThinkingAboutARP.md)). However, we can still find it with a 'brute force' search. There are several ways to do the search (e.g. `nmap`), but I'll show a method using `bash` 'cause it gives me an opportunity to practice :)

Copy the following into your editor, save it as `pingpong.sh` and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh
: ${1?"Usage: $0 ip subnet to scan. eg '192.168.0.'"}
subnet=$1
for addr in `seq 0 1 255 `; do
( ping -c 3 -t 5 $subnet$addr > /dev/null ) &
done
arp -a | grep b8:27:eb
```

Run the script with your network address as the only argument (my mac's IP is 192.168.1.75, and I know my RPi is on the same network):

```
$ ./pingpong.sh 192.168.1
```

Note that the script uses the same `arp` command that we tried earlier. If it didn't work then, it was because your Pi wasn't in your computer's `arp cache`. However, since we've now pinged it, it is in the `arp cache`.